# Oracle query for default null and on update current_timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

**Given the following mysql query:**

```
alter table foo_data
add ts timestamp NULL
default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp;
```

Could someone help me write the `plsql` query equivalent for the above `mysql` query?

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle you have to use a trigger to change the timestamp at update. The ddl (assuming that you meant the field to be not null):

```
alter table foo_data
add ts timestamp default systimestamp not null;
```

If you need the timestamp to be updated every time an update on the row occurs, you have to use a trigger like:

```
create trigger foo_data_update_ts_trigger
before update on foo_data
for each row
begin
    select systimestamp into :new.ts from dual;
end;
/
```